# jQuery slideshow with thumbnails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to do a slideshow, with the follow code:

```
<div id="galerry-one" class="gallery">
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li id="content-1"><img src="image1.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="content-2"><img src="image2.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="content-3"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/..."></iframe></li>
            <li id="content-4"><img src="image3.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="content-5"><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/..."></iframe></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbnails">
        <span class="prev"> « </span>
        <ul>
            <li id="go-content-1"><img src="image1_thumbnai.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="go-content-2"><img src="image2_thumbnai.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="go-content-3"><img src="youtube1_thumbnai.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="go-content-4"><img src="image3_thumbnai.jpg" /></li>
            <li id="go-content-5"><img src="youtube2_thumbnai.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="next"> » </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ok, when I click  the `a` with `go-content-1` id, all others slideshows hide and the `1` show, etc..

What I have started:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery').each(function(index, element) {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var images = $('#' + id + ' .content li').index() -1;

        $('#' + id + ' .prev').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if($('#' + id + ' .content .current').prev().length == 0 ) {
                $('#' + id + ' .content .current').removeClass('current').hide();
                $('#' + id + ' .content li:last').addClass('current').show();
            } else {
                $('#' + id + ' .content .current').removeClass('current').fadeOut(1000).hide().prev().fadeIn(1000).addClass('current').show();
            }

            return false;
        });

        $('#' + id + ' .next').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if($('#' + id + ' .content .current').next().length == 0 ) {
                $('#' + id + ' .content .current').removeClass('current').hide();
                $('#' + id + ' .content li:first').addClass('current').show();
            } else {
                $('#' + id + ' .content .current').removeClass('current').fadeOut(1000).hide().next().fadeIn(1000).addClass('current').show();
            }

            return false;
        });

        $('#' + id + ' .thumbnails li').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#' + id + ' .content .current').removeClass('current').hide();
            $('#' + id + ' .content .thumbnails').removeClass('current');
            $('#' + id + ' .content li').eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(1000).addClass('current').show();

            return false;
        });

        $('#' + id + ' .content li:first').addClass('current').show();
    });
});
```

The problem now is show only 4 thumbnails every time.
Thanks!

Comment: The important thing to know is the index, at all times. Take a look at this tutorial I wrote a while ago on how to create a slider, it might help http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/07/01/how-to-create-a-slideshow-plugin-with-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not hardcode numbers in id's. Use [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [prev](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).

Also I suggest reading about [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), it will increase performance in client-side and make code cleaner. Hint: use delegate instead of the second line of what you wrote.

Happy learning! :)

Comment: Implemented, but I can't do the thumbnails show/hide, showing only 4 every time.